# how to use chdir to change to current directory?

Tags: php, chdir

I'm trying to include a file from another directory and then change the chdir back to the current/original form.

```
chdir('/some/path');
include(./file.php);
chdir();//How to I change the directory back to the original form?
```

Anyway to change the chdir back to where file.php is located? or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to store the current path, before changing dirs:

```
$oldPath = getcwd();
chdir('/some/path');
include(./file.php);
chdir($oldPath);
```

Why do you need to change dirs in order to include a file?

Answer (score 0):

Save the current directory ([`getcwd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)) before you `chdir`. Then `chdir` back.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this way - chdir('../');
But really not sure in correct behavior