# How to include a script from nested folders?

Tags: php

I have this folder-structure:

```
-out
    -DBconnection.php
-root
    -application
        -contact.php
```

Also here is the content of `contact.php`:

```
function index(){
    <form action="http://example.com/localhost/application/contact/check">
        // some code here ...
    </form>
}

function check(){
    // I need to include DBconnection.php script here
    require_once( /* what path */ );
    ...
}
```

But this path doesn't work: `../../out/DBconnection.php`.

**Note:** path above works into `index()` function as well. However `index()` is defined as default in my routing system and when I open this path

```
http://example.com/contact 
/* which is the same as
   http://example.com/contact/index
*/
```

Then `index` will be executed. So how can I include `DBconnection.php` into `check()` function?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `../../out/DBconnection.php`?

Comment: @AlonEitan Sorry, I missing `out` in mentioned path. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in cases like this is to add at the very top of the root file the following lines:

```
define( 'DS',       DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'ROOT',     dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) ); // Root is ../../
```

And when I include a file, I use those constants to get the path (which is always relative to the rood document):

```
require ROOT . DS . "out" . DS . "DBconnection.php";
```

Comment: Just may you please tell me is there any alternative for this? `dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))`. Actually I cannot use `../../../` instead of that.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877297/can-i-use-dot-and-backslash-instead-of-dirname

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925679/how-to-use-chdir-to-change-to-current-directory

Answer (score 0):

try to use: ../../out/DBconnection.php

Comment: Sorry, I missing `out` in mentioned path. I edited it.

Comment: go back up another directory: ../../../out/DBconnection.php

Comment: Maybe move the `DBconnection.php` file to be inside the root directory?

Comment: I moved it out of rood directory because I wanted to keep it safe of accessing other users.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the following structure:

```
DIR1
    out
        DBconnection.php
    root
        application
            contact.php
```

So, from within `contact.php` to be able to use `DBconnection.php`, you must go up 3 directories. The correct way to do it is: `../../out/DBconnection.php`.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what is in your `include` path, and where your application gets bootstrapped.

If you're using relative paths (which you are, with the `../`), you need to understand that just because it looks relative to the file you're working on, it might not be. It's relative to the file that you 'entered' through.

To get around this, you should be able to use something like

`include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../out/DBConnection.php');`

*However*, what you really should be doing is putting your application path in your include path. That way, you'll be able to do:

`include_once('out/DBConnection.php');`

And you'll be able to do this anywhere in your application!

Comment: Ah. I may have missed a `../` in there. However, I'd really look at changing your include path using `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/your/enclosing/folder')` if you want to make this more maintainable going forward.