# Can I use dot and backslash instead of dirname()?

Tags: php

I have this path:

```
require dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/out/DBconnection.php";
```

I want to know how can I write it by dot and backslash. I wrote it like this but it doesn't work:

```
require "../../../inaccessible/dbh_conn.php";
```

What's wrong with it?

**Note:** I don't want to use `__DIR__`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Have you made sure you made the right amount of ../'s?

Answer (score 0):

Check the difference:

```
echo realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/out/DBconnection.php");
echo realpath("../../../inaccessible/dbh_conn.php")
```

I think you've got an extra `..` (and I'm assuming `inaccessible/dbh_conn.php` is the same relative path as `out/DBconnection.php` to `../..`).

Path resolving (assume current script is at `/1/2/3/4.php`):

#### dirname

1. `dirname(dirname(dirname("/1/2/3/4.php")))`
2. `dirname(dirname("/1/2/3/"))`
3. `dirname("/1/2/")`
4. `"/1/"`

#### ..

1. `"/1/2/3/../../../"`
2. `"/1/2/../.."`
3. `"/1/../"`
4. `"/"`

Comment: First one: `C:\xampp\htdocs/out/DBconnection.php`. Secound one: `../../../out/DBconnection.php`